# how to initialize hibernate connection in ServletContextListener and access any where (NON - SERVLET CLASS)?

Tags: hibernate, servletcontextlistener

how to initialize `hibernate` connection in `ServletContextListener` and access any where (`NON - SERVLET CLASS`) ?